# Background-image not working in thead (css)

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble setting a background image in a thead.

HTML:

```
    <div class="section4">
    <div class="container">
        <table class="mytable">
            <thead>
                <td class="f">F</td>
                <td class="p">P</td>
                <td class="e">E</td>
            </thead>

     .... snipped ....
```

If I start by just setting the background colour in CSS it works:

```
thead .e {
  color: #5fc98d;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

[image]

Now as soon as I change the CSS to the following I get nothing:

```
thead .e {
  color: #5fc98d;
  background: url("img/ent-star.png") no-repeat;
}
```

[image]

FYI the image is meant to be a 50px X 50px green star.

Comment: check your image path, because there is nothing wrong w your code unless you are using old `tables`

Comment: @sweaves provide more info on where images are being stored in folder structure.

Comment: Your code [seems to work perfectly fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/0busz630/), so it must be a problem with your image path.

Comment: Dang - seems that img path must be relative to CSS folder and not to the initiating HTML. going up a level worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
background: url("/img/ent-star.png") no-repeat;
background: url("../img/ent-star.png") no-repeat;
background: url("../../img/ent-star.png") no-repeat;
```

it seems that you didn't choose the correct path

see working demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ro4w3otr/

Answer (score 2):

Here's to prove that your code works, and the problem is in your image path:
https://jsfiddle.net/brbh1wfp/

```
thead .e {
  color: #5fc98d;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/50x50") no-repeat;
}
```

Suggestions: maybe your `img` folder is not in the same level as your file's folder. Try adding: `../` to go up one directory. Otherwise try an absolute path.

Quoting [this](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) article:

> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
>     there (and so on...) To move forward, just start with the first
>     subdirectory and keep moving forward.